# WP Admin messed up

Tags: wp-admin

I have updated my wordpress and some of the admin pages are messed up, it seems like CSS issue, I have deleted the cache, but it didn't fix the issue. I don't really know what is it about. Is there a way to fix it? I attach some examples. For example, if I go to add new plugin and I press Install Now or More Details, the page scrolls down and becomes blocked, only the side menu responds...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have pluign updates as well, have you tried them and see if it changes?

Also you can inspect the html code and see which css is causing the size of the images, on the browser's dev console, usually available on right click on any page.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, it was the theme that needed to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the theme, that broke the admin pages, I had to manually update the theme and it was fixed.